# How do I use the OpenSSL.Net C# wrapper to encrypt a string with AES?

Tags: c#, openssl

I am trying to send some encrypted data from my SharePoint site to my company's PeopleSoft site.  The PeopleSoft folks insist that I have to use the OpenSSL library for my encryption.  I have downloaded and installed the OpenSSL.Net project from SourceForge.

For my purposes, I need to simply encrypt a string with AES.  I know how to do this with the System.Security.Cryptography library, but am having a very difficult time translating this to the OpenSSL.Net side.  Very frustrating, since I can see everything that I think I need in Intellisense!

Does anybody have an example of performing string encryption/decryption with AES using the OpenSSL.Net wrapper?

Thanks!

-Nick

Answer (score 4):

Here is the sample which works for me. I simplified it by using copy-paste but should not matter.

I'm using text password due to compatibility with JS library but open SSL itself supports direct usage of byte[] Key and IV so it's up to you what to use.

In order to switch binary data into the string just use

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() and Encoding.UTF8.GetString()
```

to convert back and forth.

```
    public Byte[] Encrypt(Byte[] data, String password)
    {
        //Just random 8 bytes for salt
        var salt = new Byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

        using (var cc = new CipherContext(Cipher.AES_256_CBC))
        {
            //Constructing key and init vector from string password
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            byte[] iv;
            byte[] key = cc.BytesToKey(MessageDigest.MD5, salt, passwordBytes, 1, out iv);

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            //Performing encryption thru unmanaged wrapper
            var aesData = cc.Crypt(data, key, iv, true);

            //Append salt so final data will look Salted___SALT|RESTOFTHEDATA
            memoryStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Salted__"), 0, 8);
            memoryStream.Write(salt, 0, 8);
            memoryStream.Write(aesData, 0, aesData.Length);

            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public Byte[] Decrypt(String password, Byte[] encryptedData)
    {
        byte[] salt = null;
        //extracting salt if presented
        if (encryptedData.Length > 16)
        {
            if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedData).StartsWith("Salted__"))
            {
                salt = new Byte[8];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedData, 8, salt, 0, 8);
            }
        }

        //Removing salt from the original array
        int aesDataLength = encryptedData.Length - 16;
        byte[] aesData = new byte[aesDataLength];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedData, 16, aesData, 0, aesDataLength);


        using (var cc = new CipherContext(Cipher.AES_256_CBC))
        {
            //Constructing key and init vector from string password and salt
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            byte[] iv;
            byte[] key = cc.BytesToKey(MessageDigest.MD5, salt, passwordBytes, 1, out iv);

            //Decrypting
            return cc.Decrypt(aesData, key, iv, 0);

        }


    }
```

Comment: Those are some highly random eight bytes for the salt ;)

Comment: Well, random enough to answer the question as this is indeed not a live code:)

Comment: My implementation is based off of this example. I'm using the Cipher.AES_256_CBC context but if my password is < 16 bytes when cc.Crypt is called it throws an exception. Because it's trying to write the encrypted data which is 16 bytes into the 8 byte buffer it creates. Did you encounter this? I'm using OpenSSL.Net 0.4.4 and I'm using a SHA1 message digest.