# How to use openssl-net wrapper?

Tags: c#, openssl

Client is currently encrypting files using OpenSSL:

```
C:\openssl\bin"\openssl.exe smime -encrypt -des3 -in "%1.xml" -out "%1.xml.cip" "certificate.pem" >> D:\Log\log_encrypt.txt 
if errorlevel 0 (del "%1.csv")
```

Now they want to do something like this:
ERP system -> Generate Payroll -> Encrypt using OpenSSL SMIME

So my first thought was to just run above bat command from ERP system. But the problem is client doesn't want to have unencrypted payroll file on disk even for a moment (although they are already doing this with other files: save unencrypted -> encrypt -> delete unencrypted). So I have to write an app that will get data directly from ERP (that's not a problem), encrypt it using OpenSSL, and save encrypted file.

I found a c# wrapper openssl-net: https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net

To be honest I don't know how to achieve above OpenSSL smime des3 encryption using client certificate and that wrapper. Any help please? Documentation or something?

Comment: [How do I use the OpenSSL.Net C# wrapper to encrypt a string with AES?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2201631/608639)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve my problem. I still have no idea how to link it with PEM cert file i got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the same S/MIME encrypted result identical to the one produced from `openssl.exe smime -encrypt` with [OpeSSL Library for .NET](https://www.didisoft.com/openssl-net/) with the code snippet below:

```
DidiSoft.OpenSsl.Cms.OpenSslSmime smime = new DidiSoft.OpenSsl.Cms.OpenSslSmime();
smime.EncryptFile("Input.txt", "certificate.pem", @"encrypted.dat", CmsCipherAlgorithm.Des3);
```

Disclaimer: I work for DidiSoft